# How to reconsume exchange after rabbitmq server down?

Tags: rabbitmq, rabbitmq-exchange

Hi i'm wondering is there any way to try to keep continue consuming an exchange after rabbitMQ server down over .net?

Comment: Can you try describing your scenario a bit more? If you RabbitMQ Server is down there is no way you can keep consuming from it (or publishing to).

Comment: I meaning after it's back how can i keep consuming. I found the solution describing durable queue with specific queue name.